# Ext JS - Display file name in filefield

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have form with file field (upload field). After submit I want to show the file name and extension in that field.

I tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    name: 'Announcement' + i,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor: '100%',
    buttonText: 'Browse...',
    listeners:
    {
        render: function()
        {
            if (this.up('app-main-view').response.Questions[i - 1])
            {
                this.setValue(this.up('app-main-view').response.SoundFileName);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For other fields (textfields, combobox etc.) `this.setValue(this.up('app-main-view').response.SOMETHING);` works though.

Comment: What is your version of ExtJS?

Comment: The newest one... Ext JS 6.5